# Vue directive to compile custom directives

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-directives

I wrote a wrapper directive that utilizes vue's *Render* function.
Inside the render function all it does is:

```
render: function(createElement) {
    const compiled = Vue.compile(this.$props.template);
    return compiled.render.call(this, createElement);
}
```

I'm using like:

```
<Render v-for="item in itemsToRender" :key="item.id" />
```

This works for native html elements:

```
const itemsToRender = ['<p>test</p>', '<h1>HELLO</h1>'];
```

However if I pass in my own custom directive like

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

Then vue will complain about unknown components. This is probably because I don't have the custom directive imported/required in the render directive's context. Is there a work around for this? The reason I need to have this wrapper directive do the compile is because libraries like vue.Draggable, rely on 'v-for' to reorder the list elements. However, I want to be able to have different components be draggable, which is why i'm passing just templates to compile into the v-for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the component tag. Check out: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

I have made an example here: https://codepen.io/bergur/pen/jjwzEq

The flow is roughly this:

1. I register the components within my app
2. List them up in the listItemsToRender data property
3. Use the `<component>` tag to render them

Here is the code

```
new Vue({
  name: 'main',
  el: '#main',  
  components: {
    CompA,
    CompB
  },
  data() {
    return {
      header: 'Multiple components',
      itemsToRender: [CompA, CompB]           
    }
  },  
  template: `
  <div>
     {{ header }}
     <component v-for="item in itemsToRender" :is="item" />
  </div>`
})
```

Comment: You're a life saver man! I kept trying to make these wrapper directives when `<component/>` worked out of the box... This won't compile an item in itemsToRender if that item is just regular html template like `<p>hi</p>` right? If I wanted to make this generic and accept anything. Would I make a custom directive that i'd pass some type to that id use in a switch statement to return either a `<component>` or my existing Vue.Compile code?

Comment: You're right, it won't render <p>Hi</hi> unless its a component. One solution would be to make a simple component that has nothing but
<p>hi</p> as template, register it and put it in the array-list.